# How to always show video player controls on html5

Tags: html, html5-video, android-videoview

I'm looking for a way to make it so that even if a site tries to "hide" the video controls for a video, I want to override this and have the controls.

There's little more frustrating than wanting to get to the point of a video and having to sit through 15+min of BS/Advertising to get the 60seconds of content you care about.
I see many posts asking how to hide these controls, so playing devils advocate, how do I override this and make it always visible? Addin for browser? HTML code insertion? How about on mobile?

Comment: your best bet: create your own video player.